# wordpress multi user question

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, author

The blog I'm implementing will have more than one user (different analysts) but there will be only one user (call it the publisher user) who will be checking through the posts and uploading them for everyone.

The client wants me add a feature that will allow the publisher user to select which author he is posting on behalf of and that will then display that author's name.

How could a approach this issue? I was told to try something with custom fields?

Comment: i am kind of confused about your saying "which authro he is posting fro and that will then display the persons name" are you talking about setting a author for a post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple custom field and tweak your template a little,

for example say you call that custom filed "original_author"
then your theme you need to replace

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'original_author',true); ?>
```